# HTML5 applications using ExtJS 4.x

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4.1

Does ExtJS 4.x support HTML5 compliant web application development?

I am tasked to develop a single page application using ExtJS MVC architecture. Will such an application become automatically HTML5 compliant or do I have to take any steps to make it so?

Comment: @bmoeskau, The term was used in some places like http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  On this page: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/ read the section on "Cross Platform Browser Compatibility".  If you have not done much development with the Extjs framework, one of the driving design factors behind it is to create a cross-browser/platform library that looks and feels the same no matter what environment you are using.  Another of the concepts is that it utilizes HTML 5 concepts on browsers that support it and does HTML5 like things in browsers that don't support HTML 5 using other technologies (vml in IE8, etc.).  I don't think that you'll need to worry about compliance, especially if you are using the Extjs 4.x library.